# Dual monitors with 2 videos driver with xrandr 1.4

Tags: nvidia, xrandr, multi-monitor, intel, i915

I'm trying to dual-screen with 2 differents video card drivers (i915 & nvidia) but as you can see xrandr is only listing nvidia provider. I am using Arch Linux. I unsuccessfully tried finding where `xrandr` gets the provider list.

```
[x@epoch ~]$ xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x279 cap: 0x1, Source Output crtcs: 4 outputs: 6 associated providers: 0 name:NVIDIA-0

[x@epoch /etc/X11]$ sudo lshw -numeric -c video
*-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GK104 [GeForce GTX 770] [10DE:1184]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation [10DE]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:48 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-e7ffffff memory:e8000000-e9ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
  *-display
       description: Display controller
       product: Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:162]
       vendor: Intel Corporation [8086]
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:47 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

Is there any reason why it can't see the i915 one ?

Comment: Take a look at this thread: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=168427

Answer (score 1):

You have to define your GPU's in /etc/X11/xorg.conf like this:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "<BusID for NVIDIA device here>"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    # Uncomment this line if your computer has no display devices connected to
    # the NVIDIA GPU.  Leave it commented if you have display devices
    # connected to the NVIDIA GPU that you would like to use.
    #Option "UseDisplayDevice" "none"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "modesetting"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection
```

you can activate the non-NVIDIA card with the folowing commands:

```
$ xrandr --setprovideroutputsource modesetting NVIDIA-0
$ xrandr --auto
```

source: [NVIDIA Linux documentation Chapter 33](ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/319.32/README/randr14.html)

Comment: If only OP would now confirm, that it works for him... (or not). +1 for effort

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm it does indeed work. The new url to the nvidia docs page is now http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/319.12/README/randr14.html (old one does not work).

My dual monitor setup setup is GTX1080 and Intel HD Graphics 4000 (i5 3570) integrated graphic - one monitor each.

The following xorg.conf worked perfectly for me:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier      "X.org Configured"
        Screen          0  "screen_nvidia"
        Inactive        "card_intel"
        InputDevice     "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
        InputDevice     "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Files"
        ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
        FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
        Load  "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
        Identifier  "Keyboard0"
        Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
        Identifier  "Mouse0"
        Driver      "mouse"
        Option      "Protocol" "auto"
        Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
        Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier  "card_nvidia"
        Driver      "nvidia"
        BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier  "card_intel"
        Driver      "modesetting"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier "screen_nvidia"
        Device     "card_nvidia"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier "screen_intel"
        Device     "card_intel"
EndSection
```